# In linux, how to watch window creating event in bash or c or c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash

unity linux editor always popup "Hold On" even my current window is not unity editor, so I hope minimize "Hold On" win when this win creating, here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# regex for extracting hex id's
grep_id='0[xX][a-zA-Z0-9]\{7\}'

xprop -spy -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | grep --line-buffered -o $grep_id |
while read -r id; do
    class="`xprop -id $id WM_CLASS | grep Unity`"
    win_title="`xprop -id $id WM_NAME | grep Hold\ On`"
    if [ -n "$class" ] && [ -n "$win_title" ]; then
      xdotool windowminimize $id
    fi
done
```

but above code has problem, _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW will be triggered each time I active "Hold On", I only need minimize "Hold On" on window creating, how should i do?

in linux xfce, "Window Manager" > "automatically give focus to newly created window", so I guess exist some way to watch window creating event
[image]

Comment: This is, unfortunately, something that only a window manager can do. It overrides MapWindow, and then does things like create a frame (for a non override-redirect window) and then reparent the new window into the frame, before it gets mapped. Automatically giving focus is done as part of that process.

Answer (score 0):

here is my ruby solution: I cache minimized window ids, one window only minimize once

```
system %Q(notify-send "auto hide Unity 'Hold On' popup, conf: #{__FILE__}")
# bash_script = File.expand_path("../../sh/auto_hide_unity_hold_on_popup.sh", __FILE__)
# system "bash #{bash_script}"

pipe = IO.popen("xprop -spy -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW")
wids = []
while (line = pipe.gets)
  wid = line.match(%r{0x[\da-z]{2,}})
  kls = `xprop -id #{wid} WM_CLASS | grep Unity`
  win_title = `xprop -id #{wid} WM_NAME | grep "Hold On"`
  if !wids.include?(wid) && kls != "" && win_title != ""
    wids << wid
    if (wids.size > 20)
      wids = wids[-20..-1]
    end
    `xdotool windowminimize #{wid}`
  end
end
```